# Accessing of iphone library books into our application in iPad

Tags: iphone

i am developing an application which is basically a book reader app.

what i want is, should be able download a book from the gutenberg site into iphone book library and when ever my application opens i need to scan the native iBooks library and show all the books list, kind of showing the adressbook.

is it possible to scan the iphone iBook library and get all the available books in the device?

please give your valuable suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official way to scan the iBooks app books.

iBook is not part of iOS and the offical SDK, you will need to setup your own library from which to download.

Comment: is stanza,kindle,Eucalyptus book applications are using their own libraries to get the books from gutenberg? please give me any suggestions that how we can get the books from gutenberg.